# Did Anakin and Obi-Wan use the Force to protect themselves from the heat on Mustafar?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, revenge-of-the-sith

While duelling that close to lava, I would suspect that they would get dangerously hot and dehydrated, and possibly burned. Did they use the Force to protect themselves in some way, for example lower their body temperatures and cool the air around them while duelling?

Comment: Not according to the novelization

Comment: How so? What did the novelization specify?

Comment: Didn't mention the head

Comment: The droid gatherer that Anakin stepped on had some sort of shielding, possible this protected Anakin. You can clearly see the shielding effects in the movie. Not sure but guessing Obi-wan's platform had the same shielding.

Comment: @Jared That's what I thought too, but then there's also the part of the battle when they were fighting on the gantry and swinging back and forth like Tarzan above a literal river of lava.  Despite the exertion and furnace-like conditions, neither of them were even sweating at that point.  Once Anakin got Ginsu'd, he held out a while longer but eventually went up like a Presto log.  So I think Force-protection is as good an explanation as any.

Comment: In light of the quote from the DVD commentary, I was wondering if you'd like to consider offering an acceptance (or if you're still not happy, some indication of why)?

Answer (score 5):

The DVD commentary for Episode III (with producer [Rick McCallum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_McCallum#Star_Wars)) explains this in more detail. In short, the blue haze you see is not only a repulsor field but it also creates a form of cooling for the Jedi:

> **Rick McCallum :** *This blue light around the bottom of the light and the platforms was added later on, in Production. George felt that
>   at one point, that we needed to feel that there was some cooling
>   effect, some kind of shield...a reason why our actors aren't burning
>   up being around this intense heat so Roger Guyett and his team added
>   these shields, this shield generator into this shots as another pass
>   after they'd completed a lot of these shots...to help tell that story
>   of the cooling*.

Comment: This plus the force?

Comment: Thus making this one of the few cases where the (apparent) lack of convection is actually justified.

Comment: @JustinTime - Indeed. Although it's kinda dumb, based on the tech seen elsewhere in the films, it's actually pretty consistent with what can be done in the Star Wars universe.

Answer (score 3):

There are many planets in the EU that are unrealistic.  One of them is Mustafar.  That much volcanic activity would not only raise the temperature of the air but fill it with toxins so as to make the air poisonous to breathe.   The land was also shown as basically stable.  But the forces required to maintain heat so as to keep the rivers of lava flowing molten on the surface, would require the entire landscape to be tortured by tidal  forces, resulting in a constantly shifting landscape that is basically a flat shelf of rock floating on a molten see just a few dosen yards at its thickest.

The Star Wars EU requires some suspension of disbelief.  One of them is that there is a planet that has molten lava flowing all over it surface is small streams that does not destabilize the crust, create excessive heat, or completely poison the air.

Comment: "But the forces required to maintain heat so as to keep the rivers of lava flowing molten on the surface, would require the entire landscape to be tortured by tidal forces" except for the fact that only a small amount of internal heating comes from tidal forces.  It's mostly from radioactive decay and heat stored since formation.  Heating can even potentially come from dark matter (and yes, there are physics papers about this).  The EU is a mess, but the presence of magma itself isn't a part of that.

Comment: @AlanSE - But mustafar is crisscrossed with rivers of molten lava.  Look at what happens in Hawaii.  The lava forms tubes that isulate it from the loss of heat.  You would need instability to maintain open rivers of lava.  And if there is enough heat being generated by radioactivity to melt and maitain a molten state... then Mustafar is even more dangerous than if it is the tidal forces causing the heating.  I am sure there are lots of ways this could work... but none that would also permit humans to walk around basically unprotected in normal gravity and atmosphere.

Comment: In the case of Mustafar it's _definitely_ tidal forces.  Mustafar is the moon of an even larger world and in the movie we can plainly see that Mustafar is close to, if not well inside, its own [Roche limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit).  Mustafar is well on its way to disintegrating and forming a ring system and that explains the monstrous lava flows and general chaos over the whole surface of the planet.

Answer (score 1):

As Chad answered, there are a lot of things which are considered in our world unreal, like the **Jedi powers themselves**. We see that Jedi can do a lot by using the force and I cannot see any reason why it should be in this case otherwise.

For example, in the Episode 1, in the very beginning, we can see that they are able to hold their breath in a poisonous environment longer that normal human being. So they definitely posses the ability to survive in hostile environment.

You can also see that Anakin, after the combat with Obi-Wan, caught on fire. My understanding "why not before(?)" is: because his **ability to use the force diminished**.

So my answer is **YES**, they used the force to survive under the hostile condition, like they do all the time.